# Showing that the Cantor Set is sequentially compact

Tags: real-analysis

It's easy to show that the Cantor Set (CS) is sequentially compact by the fact that it's closed and bounded.

But how do I prove this fact by showing that every sequence in the CS has a subsequence that converges to an element in the CS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [ternary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system), Cantor set consists of numbers $0.x_1 x_2 x_3\ldots$ such that each $x_i$ is $0$ or $2$, not $1$. Choose $x_1$ to be $0$ or $2$ such that infinitely many elements of the sequence have $x_1$ on the first position. Then choose $x_2$ such that infinitely many elements have $0.x_1 x_2$ on the first and second position, and so on. Then the subsequence
$a_{i_1}:=0.x_1 [\text{anything}], a_{i_2}:=0.x_1 x_2 [\text{anything}]$, $\ldots$, $a_{i_k}=0.x_1 x_2\ldots x_k [\text{anything}]$, $\ldots$ can be found in the sequence and it obviously converges to $0. x_1 x_2 x_3 \ldots$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. How can you formally show that its limit is in fact $0.x_1x_2x_3...$?

Comment: The distance beteren this number and the nth element of the sequence goes to zero.